# DropDown allowing selection and entering Text in .NET MAUI

Tags: maui, picker

In one of my Views, I wanted to have a possibility to Save and Load stored items (of type `ObservableRangeCollection<ItemModel>`) that are listed in a CollectionView on this View.

Previously, in Windows-Programming I could use a ComboBox which did allow to enter some text and select items from a DropDown. In combination with a Save-Button this could store the values with the selected or entered Name from the ComboBox.

I don't know, what the best option is to solve this under .NET MAUI? First of all, I thought a simple Picker could do the job. But, I can't enter any Text and also when I try to load the relevant Data from the following Collection, I am not able to provide the right way to display the string in the Picker, but have the relevant items from the value of the Dictionary somewhere:

`new ObservableRangeCollection<Dictionary<string, ObservableRangeCollection<ItemModel>>>();`

What is your recommendation - so, how can this be solved? As I do not have much space for that on my View, a Picker would have been good.

=== Added Code for CustomPopup View based on the Community Toolkit ===

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<toolkit:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views;assembly=CommunityToolkit.Maui"
             x:Class="MyApp.Pages.CustomPicker.CustomPopupView">
    
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
    
</toolkit:Popup>
```

**Other ContentView providing the Entry with Arrow-Down-Button**

```
public class CustomPicker : ContentView
{
    public CustomPicker()
    {
        var entry = new Entry
        {
            Placeholder = "Enter a Text...",
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };

        var button = new Button
        {
            Text = "▼",
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            WidthRequest = 40
        };

        button.Clicked += OnButtonClicked;

        var grid = new Grid
        {
            ColumnDefinitions = new ColumnDefinitionCollection
            {
                new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Auto },
                new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Star },
            },
        };

        grid.Add(entry, 0, 0);
        grid.Add(button, 1, 0);

        Content = grid;
    }

    private async void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       
        var mainPage = Application.Current.MainPage;
        mainPage.ShowPopup(new CustomPopupView());
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a ListView or CollectionView with a SearchBox

Comment: Would be an option, but needs quite some height then, right? Is there a way to create such a custom picker that allows to enter a Text when clicked into it and just opens the bound items of the ItemsSource, when the little Arrow on the right is clicked? I saw a custom ComboBox from Syncfusion

Comment: @OXO Do what Jason told you. This drop down arrow might as well expand a view with your collection view, trigger some custom animation, or plain and simple change IsVisible attribute. When selected you modify the entry text property. It is that simple. Edit: (I use a popup for this, far from ideal, but in my case it works for me)

Comment: I thought about using a Popup-View for the Popup itself and when a Button with a Down-Arrow (as a replacement for the ComboBox-Arrow) is clicked it will display this PopupView as a Popup => this.ShowPopup(new MyPopupView()).

The only problem is, that I can't use this.ShowPopup(...) unless it is called from a ContentPage

Comment: I changed it and created a new ContentView which is used as a Popup and should actually display the CollectionView etc.  -  The Entry and Button for Arrow-Down (which should be the imitation of the ComboBox) is defined in another View. When the Button with the Arrow-Down is clicked, I call ```var mainPage = Application.Current.MainPage; mainPage.ShowPopup(new CustomPopupView());``` to actually display my CustomPopupView. Hope this is okay? How would I set the Height/Width so that it is expanded/filled correctly as it would be on the platform (iOS, Android or whatever platform)

Comment: What is not working as expected is that this new ContentView should be layouted based on the Parent in which it is embedded, so that it is maybe filled horizontally but have a certain Padding inside or something like that. Don't know what feels naturally and provides the best option when dealing with potentially different display sizes on different devices

Answer (score 1):

I have created a ComboBox class with the listview and the entry. I refer to the resourc code about a combobox control in the xamarin on the github.

Here is the code:

```
public class ComboBox : StackLayout
    {
        private Entry _entry;
        private ListView _listView;
        private bool _supressFiltering;
        private bool _supressSelectedItemFiltering;
        //Bindable properties
        public static readonly BindableProperty ListViewHeightRequestProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ListViewHeightRequest), typeof(double), typeof(ComboBox), defaultValue: null, propertyChanged: (bindable, oldVal, newVal) => {
            var comboBox = (ComboBox)bindable;
            comboBox._listView.HeightRequest = (double)newVal;
        });
        public double ListViewHeightRequest
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(ListViewHeightRequestProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ListViewHeightRequestProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly BindableProperty EntryBackgroundColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(EntryBackgroundColor), typeof(Color), typeof(ComboBox), defaultValue: null, propertyChanged: (bindable, oldVal, newVal) => {
            var comboBox = (ComboBox)bindable;
            comboBox._entry.BackgroundColor = (Color)newVal;
        });
        public Color EntryBackgroundColor
        {
            get { return (Color)GetValue(EntryBackgroundColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(EntryBackgroundColorProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly BindableProperty EntryFontSizeProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(EntryFontSize), typeof(double), typeof(ComboBox), defaultValue: null, propertyChanged: (bindable, oldVal, newVal) => {
            var comboBox = (ComboBox)bindable;
            comboBox._entry.FontSize = (double)newVal;
        });
        [TypeConverter(typeof(FontSizeConverter))]
        public double EntryFontSize
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(EntryFontSizeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(EntryFontSizeProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemsSource), typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(ComboBox), defaultValue: null, propertyChanged: (bindable, oldVal, newVal) => {
            var comboBox = (ComboBox)bindable;
            comboBox._listView.ItemsSource = (IEnumerable)newVal;
        });
        public IEnumerable ItemsSource
        {
            get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedItemProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SelectedItem), typeof(object), typeof(ComboBox), defaultValue: null, propertyChanged: (bindable, oldVal, newVal) => {
            var comboBox = (ComboBox)bindable;
            comboBox._listView.SelectedItem = newVal;
        });
        public object SelectedItem
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
        }
        public static new readonly BindableProperty VisualProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Visual), typeof(IVisual), typeof(ComboBox), defaultValue: new DefaultVisual(), propertyChanged: (bindable, oldVal, newVal) => {
            var comboBox = (ComboBox)bindable;
            comboBox._listView.Visual = (IVisual)newVal;
            comboBox._entry.Visual = (IVisual)newVal;
        });
        public new IVisual Visual
        {
            get { return (IVisual)GetValue(VisualProperty); }
            set { SetValue(VisualProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly BindableProperty PlaceholderProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Placeholder), typeof(string), typeof(ComboBox), defaultValue: "", propertyChanged: (bindable, oldVal, newVal) => {
            var comboBox = (ComboBox)bindable;
            comboBox._entry.Placeholder = (string)newVal;
        });
        public string Placeholder
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(PlaceholderProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PlaceholderProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(ComboBox), defaultValue: "", propertyChanged: (bindable, oldVal, newVal) => {
            var comboBox = (ComboBox)bindable;
            comboBox._entry.Text = (string)newVal;
        });
        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly BindableProperty ItemTemplateProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemTemplate), typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(ComboBox), defaultValue: null, propertyChanged: (bindable, oldVal, newVal) => {
            var comboBox = (ComboBox)bindable;
            comboBox._listView.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)newVal;
        });
        public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
        {
            get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly BindableProperty EntryDisplayPathProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(EntryDisplayPath), typeof(string), typeof(ComboBox), defaultValue: "");
        public string EntryDisplayPath
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(EntryDisplayPathProperty); }
            set { SetValue(EntryDisplayPathProperty, value); }
        }
        public event EventHandler<SelectedItemChangedEventArgs> SelectedItemChanged;
        protected virtual void OnSelectedItemChanged(SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler<SelectedItemChangedEventArgs> handler = SelectedItemChanged;
            handler?.Invoke(this, e);
        }
        public event EventHandler<TextChangedEventArgs> TextChanged;
        protected virtual void OnTextChanged(TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler<TextChangedEventArgs> handler = TextChanged;
            handler?.Invoke(this, e);
        }
        public ComboBox()
        {
            //Entry used for filtering list view
            _entry = new Entry();
            _entry.Margin = new Thickness(0);
            _entry.Keyboard = Keyboard.Create(KeyboardFlags.None);
            _entry.Focused += (sender, args) => _listView.IsVisible = true;
            _entry.Unfocused += (sender, args) => _listView.IsVisible = false;
            //Text changed event, bring it back to the surface
            _entry.TextChanged += (sender, args) =>
            {
                if (_supressFiltering)
                    return;
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(args.NewTextValue))
                {
                    _supressSelectedItemFiltering = true;
                    _listView.SelectedItem = null;
                    _supressSelectedItemFiltering = false;
                }
                _listView.IsVisible = true;
                OnTextChanged(args);
            };
            //List view - used to display search options
            _listView = new ListView();
            _listView.IsVisible = false;
            _listView.Margin = new Thickness(0);
            Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific.ListView.SetSeparatorStyle(_listView, Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific.SeparatorStyle.FullWidth);
            _listView.HeightRequest = 100;
            _listView.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand;
            _listView.SetBinding(ListView.SelectedItemProperty, new Binding(nameof(ComboBox.SelectedItem), source: this));
            //Item selected event, surface it back to the top
            _listView.ItemSelected += (sender, args) =>
            {
                if (!_supressSelectedItemFiltering)
                {
                    _supressFiltering = true;
                    var selectedItem = args.SelectedItem;
                    _entry.Text = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(EntryDisplayPath) && selectedItem != null ? selectedItem.GetType().GetProperty(EntryDisplayPath).GetValue(selectedItem, null).ToString() : selectedItem?.ToString();
                    _supressFiltering = false;
                    _listView.IsVisible = false;
                    OnSelectedItemChanged(args);
                    _entry.Unfocus();
                }
            };
            //Add bottom border
            var boxView = new BoxView();
            boxView.HeightRequest = 1;
            boxView.Color = Colors.Black;
            boxView.Margin = new Thickness(0);
            boxView.SetBinding(BoxView.IsVisibleProperty, new Binding(nameof(ListView.IsVisible), source: _listView));
            Children.Add(_entry);
            Children.Add(_listView);
            Children.Add(boxView);
           
        }
        public new bool Focus()
        {
            return _entry.Focus();
        }
        public new void Unfocus()
        {
            _entry.Unfocus();
        }
    }
```

And use it in the xaml:

```
 <local:ComboBox x:Name="combobox"  SelectedItemChanged="combobox_SelectedItemChanged"/>
```

And set the itemsource in the code behind:

```
combobox.ItemsSource = new List<string>() { "item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5" };
```

Hope this can help you!